# Split lines (like fmt -w) but on coloured / formatted command line output

Tags: command-line, colors, macos, text-formatting

I have output from a command (`jest`, for running automated JS tests) that uses fancy terminal codes to do things like coloured text in its output.  I want to trim any very long lines because I run jest from emacs, and emacs has a long-standing issue of poor performance on long lines.

If I use something like piping the output of jest to `fmt -w 200`, the terminal formatting becomes not visible in emacs, and the output is hard to read (this is using the Mac OS fmt).

How can I split long lines preserving terminal formatting?

Comment: I've just realised that GNU fmt does this already.  Going to test that on mac os and then answer my own question I guess

Answer (score 0):

The `fmt` from GNU coreutils provides this functionality.

On Mac OS, this can be installed, under the name `gfmt`, using homebrew with `brew install coreutils`.